# Circle geometry transformation diagram

Tags: diagrams

I would like to create that kind of diagram. What solution/package should I use ? (arrow don't need to be such fancy shape)

[image: circle geometry transformation diagram]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tikz` attempt:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  x rectangle/.style={
    minimum height=3em,
    minimum width=5.5em,
    rectangle,
    align=center,
    text depth=.5ex,
    text height=2em,
    draw,
    text=red!50!black,
    node font=\bfseries,
  },
  x circle/.style={
    minimum size=3em,
    circle,
    draw
  },
  x edge/.style={
    arrows={-{Stealth[length=2mm]}},
    bend angle=55,
    bend left,
    every edge quotes/.style={x circle, fill=white}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[nodes={x rectangle}, node distance=10em]
    node             (r) {r\\radius}
    node[right of=r] (d) {d\\diameter}
    node[right of=d] (p) {p\\perimeter};

  \path[x edge]
    (r) edge["$\times 2$"]   (d)
    (d) edge["$\times \pi$"] (p)
    (p) edge["$\colon \pi$"] (d)
    (d) edge["$\colon 2$"]   (r);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I guess the tricky part is the 3d arrows?

Comment: @Anush Yes. Looks like they need some non-linear transformation.